# How can i test the if branch inside this function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, branch

```
onSelect(event: any) {
    if (event.type === 'GROUP') {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

I´ve mocked event.

```
    function event(): any {
  return [
    {
      originalEvent: {
        isTrusted: true,
      },
      query: 'MeNu',
    },
    {
      originalEvent: {
        isTrusted: true,
      },
      query: 'MeNu',
      url: '/i2s-life',
      type: 'GROUP',
    },
    {
      originalEvent: {
        isTrusted: true,
      },
      query: 'MeNu',
      url: '/i2s-life',
      type: 'EMBED',
    },
  ];
}
```

And made following SPEC test:

```
it('should select event with type GROUP', () => {
    const ev = event()[1];
    component.onSelect(event());
    expect(ev.type).toEqual('GROUP');
  });
```

But the if branch does not get covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send the argument `ev` and not `event()`.

Like this:

```
it('should select event with type GROUP', () => {
    const ev = event()[1];
    const select = component.onSelect(ev);
    expect(select).toBeNull();
  });
```